# How to sum up all associated records from join table in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models in my Ruby on Rails app :

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :allocations
  has_many :payments, :through   => :allocations

end
```

---

```
class Allocation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :payment

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :allocations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoices,    :through => :allocations

end
```

---

My problem is that in the `Allocation` class I would like to use the `total_amount` of all associated invoices, ideally in a `before_save` callback.

This isn't possible right now, however, because at the time an `allocation` object gets saved it is only associated with *one* particular `invoice` object.

How can this be done with a minimum of database queries?

Comment: Any particular `Allocation` is only ever associated with a single `Invoice`. It sounds like you actually want `Invoice` to have your `total_amount` method, and that is actually very straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Invoice.where(asdfasdfasdf).map(&:allocations).flatten.map(&:total_amount).compact.inject(:+)
```

Because this is rails the database call is nothing. To sum up an array of numbers you can use this:

```
ary = [0,12,2,6,nil]
ary.compact.inject(:+)
#=> 20
```

You could clean this up a bit:

```
class Invoice
#...
  def total_amount
    allocations.map(&:total_amount).inject(:+) #throws error if there is 1 nil 'total_amount data' value
  end 

  def self.sum_allocation_amounts(sql)
    where(sql).map(&:total_amount).inject(:+)
  end

end
```

Its not possible to call `self.map(&:allocations)` inside of an Invoice class method without errors so I'm passing in the some basic sql as a workaround. Ideally I'd make it possible to directly call this method on a daisy chain of activerecord where calls for Invoice but that's not working out for me right now ("undefined method map' for Class")

```
Invoice.sum_allocation_amounts("democol = 'demo params'")
```